# AFNetworking Request response bad request (400)

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, nsurlrequest

I am using AFNetworking to make a call to server. The server have NTLM authentication on. I am using **setWillSendRequestForAuthenticationChallengeBlock** for handling that authentication.

My problem is that when I make a call the server first time, it works flawlessly. But when I make the same call to the server again I get **bad request (400)** error. Here is my code:

```
-(AFHTTPRequestOperation *)POST:(NSString *)URLString parameters:(id)parameters success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *, id))success failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *, NSError *))failure {

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[self.baseURL absoluteString],URLString]]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil]]
;

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.shouldUseCredentialStorage = NO;

operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:success failure:failure];

[self addChallengeBlockForOperation:operation failure:^(NSError *error) {
    failure(operation,error);
}];

//[self.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
[operation start];

return operation;
}

- (void)addChallengeBlockForOperation:(AFHTTPRequestOperation *)operation failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure {
[operation setWillSendRequestForAuthenticationChallengeBlock:^(NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *challenge) {
    if( [[challenge protectionSpace] authenticationMethod] == NSURLAuthenticationMethodNTLM )
    {
        if( [challenge previousFailureCount] > 0 )
        {
            // Avoid too many failed authentication attempts which could lock out the user
            [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        }
        else
        {
            [[challenge sender] useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:[DataManager sharedInstance].fullUserName password:[DataManager sharedInstance].password persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceSynchronizable] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Authenticate in other ways than NTLM if desired or cancel the auth like this:
        [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
}];
}
```

I know I can remove this error by adding **text/html** to accepted types but that is not the solution. I should be able to get JSON response the second time as well. I also get **Stream xxxxx is sending an event before being opened** on the console once for the first call and twice for the second call.

I have hidden the URL for security purposes in the log. Here is my log:

```
2015-12-03 16:14:04.854 iOS Docketing App[740:195426] *************Users/Authenticate/**************
2015-12-03 16:14:04.884 iOS Docketing App[740:195426] POST 'http:.....': {
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
} {
  "userName" : "tkxel2"
}
2015-12-03 16:14:08.659 iOS Docketing App[740:195566] Stream 0x17f42a10 is sending an event before being opened
2015-12-03 16:14:09.473 iOS Docketing App[740:195426] 200 'http:.....' [4.5876 s]: {
    "Cache-Control" = private;
    "Content-Length" = 61;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Thu, 03 Dec 2015 11:14:13 GMT";
    "Persistent-Auth" = false;
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/7.5";
    Via = "1.1 vm-magagent.ntcorp.local, 1.1 vm-magrelay.skgf.com";
    "X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
} {"practiceGroupName":"Egroup","role":"P","username":"tkxel2"}
2015-12-03 16:14:09.486 iOS Docketing App[740:195426] *************Users/Authenticate/**************
2015-12-03 06:14:09:478 iOS Docketing App[740:195426] __59-[NetworkHelper authenticateWithUserName:success:AndError:]_block_invoke Time: 4.619750 seconds Size: 104 bytes
2015-12-03 16:14:09.493 iOS Docketing App[740:195426] POST 'http:.....': {
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
} {
  "userName" : "tkxel2"
}
2015-12-03 16:14:10.434 iOS Docketing App[740:195566] Stream 0x17a36010 is sending an event before being opened
2015-12-03 16:14:10.710 iOS Docketing App[740:195566] Stream 0x17b63ae0 is sending an event before being opened
2015-12-03 16:14:10.992 iOS Docketing App[740:195426] 400 'http:.....' [1.4990 s]: {
    "Cache-Control" = private;
    "Content-Length" = 1647;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Thu, 03 Dec 2015 11:14:14 GMT";
    "Persistent-Auth" = false;
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/7.5";
    Via = "1.1 vm-magagent.ntcorp.local, 1.1 vm-magrelay.skgf.com";
    "X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
} <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head>

    <title>Request Error</title>

    <style>BODY { color: #000000; background-color: white; font-family: Verdana; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; } #content { margin-left: 30px; font-size: .70em; padding-bottom: 2em; } A:link { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } A:visited { color: #6699cc; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } A:active { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } .heading1 { background-color: #003366; border-bottom: #336699 6px solid; color: #ffffff; font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 26px; font-weight: normal;margin: 0em 0em 10px -20px; padding-bottom: 8px; padding-left: 30px;padding-top: 16px;} pre { font-size:small; background-color: #e5e5cc; padding: 5px; font-family: Courier New; margin-top: 0px; border: 1px #f0f0e0 solid; white-space: pre-wrap; white-space: -pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; } table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; font-family: Verdana;} table th { border-right: 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white solid; font-weight: bold; background-color: #cecf9c;} table td { border-right: 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white solid; background-color: #e5e5cc;}</style>

  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="content">

      <p class="heading1">Request Error</p>

      <p>The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details.</p>

    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: "The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details.". Seems to be an error on the server side.

Comment: But when I hit the server from a REST console no matter how many times, I get the correct response.

Comment: I have debugged the issue a little more and figured out that the authentication challenge block is not being called on the second call. How do I force it to call the challenge block everytime?

Comment: It gets into the challenge block the second time but i am still getting the same error. Where are the Awesome members of stackoverflow?